# Unconditionally secure message authentication, how does it work?

Tags: authentication

The definition of an unconditionally secure cryptosystem is that it cannot be broken even with infinitely computational resources and time. The one-time pad (OTP) is an example of an unconditionally secure system, there is nothing in the ciphertext that makes one message seem more probable than the other, brute-force cryptanalysis is in vain because every plaintext is equally likely, even with infinite computational resources and time. OTP is unconditionally secure encryption. Is there also unconditionally secure message authentication, and if there is, how does it work?

Comment: This question is more generic, focusing on how unconditionally secure message authentication is unconditionally secure.

Comment: Yes, but the answer I wrote on the other question addresses this one.